# Retaining other column in dataframe when using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe as shown here:

| user_id | platform | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | confidence_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Movies Lovers | Horror Movies Fans | 0.69 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Mobile Enthusiasts | High Data Users | 0.43 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Travellers | Local Commuters | 0.17 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Movie Lovers | English Movies Fans | 0.47 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Movie Lovers | Indonesian Movies Fans | 0.37 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | iflix Viewing Behaviour | casual | 1.00 |

I need to groupby the data by user id, platform, level 1, level 2 and select the max value of confidence while retaining the level 3 field. How can this be done?? I have tried using groupby(), but the level 3 columns is removed.

The expected output is as below

| user_id | platform | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | confidence_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13915694042520 | android | Psychographics | Movies Lovers | Horror Movies Fans | 0.69 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Mobile Enthusiasts | High Data Users | 0.43 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Travellers | Local Commuters | 0.17 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | Movie Lovers | English Movies Fans | 0.47 |
| 1391569404252 | android | Psychographics | flix Viewing Behaviour | casual | 1.00 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.idxmax`:

```
keys = ["user_id", "platform", "level_1", "level_2"]
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby(keys)["confidence_score"].idxmax()]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         user_id platform         level_1                  level_2  \
1  1391569404252  android  Psychographics       Mobile Enthusiasts   
3  1391569404252  android  Psychographics             Movie Lovers   
0  1391569404252  android  Psychographics            Movies Lovers   
2  1391569404252  android  Psychographics               Travellers   
5  1391569404252  android  Psychographics  iflix Viewing Behaviour   

               level_3  confidence_score  
1      High Data Users              0.43  
3  English Movies Fans              0.47  
0   Horror Movies Fans              0.69  
2      Local Commuters              0.17  
5               casual              1.00
```